# Multiple Foreign Keys Data models update in EF using c# mvc context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, eager-loading

Suppose I have following models.

```
public class modelA 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class modelB 
{
    [key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public modelA modelAID {get; set;}
}

public class modelC 
{
    [key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public modelA modelAID {get; set;}
    public modelB modelBID {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have controller action which insert modelC.

```
public ActionResult addModelC()
{
    modelA dbModelA = db.modelAs.FirstOrDefault();
    modelB dbModelB = db.modelBs.FirstOrDefault();

    modelC newModelC = new modelC();
    newModelC.Name = "New Model C";
    newModelC.modelAID = dbModelA;
    newModelC.modelBID = dbModelB;

    db.modelCs.Add(newModelC);
    db.SaveChanges(); //DbEntityValidation error on dbModelB.modelAID empty because its not included when db.modelBs query was called
}
```

If I dont eager load modelAID in db.modelBs EF will try to create new record on saveChanges(). How to stop this?

How can add `modelC` without including (eager loading) modelA and modelB. I only need to add foreign keys relation. Here at SaveChanges it also try to update modelA and modelB but I dont want to update those. I know EF needs to know everything but due to large record eagerly loading might raise memory issue.

```
db.modelCs.include(i=>i.modelAID).include(i=>i.modelBID).ToList();
```

If I dont need to inner join modelAID modelBID. and only show modelC.

Also in some cases if I return modelC as JSON object it says circular reference found because it has repeating modelAID one in modelB and one in modelC. I hope I make it clear.

Note:using code first approach.

Comment: foreign keys are normally created using the keyword `virtual`. In your example, I suspect you must use: `public virtual modelA modelAID { get; set; }`

Comment: If I use virtual it will start lazy loading. What I want is, not to load related objects.

Answer (score 0):

[from memory]
You need to use the FK conventions to allow you to link these together

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2

```
// Foreign key 
public int modelAID { get; set; } 

// Navigation properties 
public virtual ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
```

So when creating `modelC`, you only need to assign the `modelAID = modelA.Id` and the relationship is set. Then when loading `modelC`, you can either let EF dynamically load `ModelA` (beware of N+1 scenario's) or you can force EF to load ModelA by using `.include`

Comment: I created modelB as you wright above. It only changes my database ForeignKey column from modelAID_ID to modelAID. Still if I don't include modelAID db.modelBs.include("modelAID") when I save changes it tries to create new modelA and says primary key already exist in database. Why I have to include. I dont need modelA from modelB I have modelA in modelC. Both have different relationship to modelC.